# MySQL ignore query results with column that appears more than once

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to count the number of rows in my database where the gross is 50 and the name only appears one time. this is the query i have that i was convinced would work

```
SELECT name,
       gross
FROM   daysheet
WHERE  gross = '50'
GROUP  BY name
HAVING Count(name) = 1
```

However, this doesnt seem to be working the way i thought it should be.

```
GROSS      NAME
 50      Person 1
 50      Person 2
 705     Person 2
```

Above is an example of the table. I want my query to return 1 row because 50 appears 1 time where the name is completely unique, yet the query above is returning 2 for this

I've also tried using DISTINCT but its always returning 2.

Where have i gone wrong?

Thanks!

Clarification: I am trying to retrieve the number of rows where the gross is 50 and the name only appears 1 time in the database. So Person 2 would be ignored since it appears twice, and the num rows should be 1, since only 1 time is there a gross of 50 and a name that only appears one time

Comment: You have used `SELECT DISTINCT name`? If not, where did you place the `DISTINCT`?

Comment: @AmazingDreams `"SELECT DISTINCT name, gross FROM daysheet WHERE gross = '50'"` is still returning 2

Comment: Let me get this straight: you want only one record per person, or only records, where person is not repeated? In other words, you should get "50 - Person 1"?

Comment: @DavidJashi Where only person is not repeated

Comment: @robz228 Still can't get it. Can you update question with records you want to get?

Comment: What does this give you? SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name = 'person 2'

Comment: What is the expected output? since you have `Person 1` and `Person 2` you will always get 2 rows as long as `name` appears in the select clause(unless you filter it out).

Comment: @Verma expected output for num_rows should be 1, only 1 record in the database contains a gross of 50 with a completely unique name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
select name, gross
from   daysheet d1
where  gross = 50
and    1 in (select count(name)
             from daysheet d2
             where d2.name = d1.name)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be634/1

Comment: Clearly i need to learn more! Would have never even thought of this. Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name,
       gross
FROM   daysheet
GROUP  BY name, gross
HAVING Count(name) = 1
```

should be ok

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
SELECT name, gross FROM daysheet WHERE gross='50' and name in 
(SELECT name FROM daysheet GROUP BY name HAVING count(name)=1)
```